# Puppeteer hides cells borders when backgroundColor is applied

Tags: puppeteer

Generally Puppeteer makes pdf as it's expected without **backgroundColor** (table cells can have colspan/rowspan):

[image]

But, if { backgroundColor: #c1c1c1; } is applied cell borders disappear randomly:

[image]

How apply backgroundColor to table and preserve cell borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using colors with opacity, f.e. `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`